# How to block multiple usage of an enum element to a macro function during compile time

Tags: c, macros, compile-time

Please find the sample code below

```
typedef enum {
    ID_001 = 1,
    ID_002 = 2,
    ID_003 = 3,
}ENM_t;
#define ERR(en) {printf("ID = %d\n", en);}
int main()
{  
    ERR(ID_001);
    ERR(ID_003);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to give a compile time error if I pass same enum element multiple time to macro function 'ERR'?. The above program should compile without any error, if I use
ERR(ID_001);
ERR(ID_001);
then it should give a compile time error.

Comment: Without your own preprocessor to check for this specific case, then no it's not possible. And *why* do you want this? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: I've a huge code and many ERR calls. ID to pass should only ones for the whole code.

Comment: Unit-testing, code-review, and possibly automatic checking through a custom checker program are the ways you can do it. There's no way to get a compiler error from what is essentially valid code.

Comment: Text search through the whole project should be one of the programmer's most frequently used tools. Simply search for each item in the enum one at a time?

Comment: It's possible to get this for a single function (e.g. generate labels with names based on the parameter, a duplicate would error out, see https://godbolt.org/z/6osPqE ). I don't have a good idea of how you might get that for a whole program though.

Comment: You could do a `grep` on `ID_` and then sort the output. Any duplicate use can be found with your eyes.